# Error replace image tag to image src

Tags: php

```
$content = 'This fairy tale-like place is based on a story of two lovers who ran away to escape their enemies.
<img src="blisshouse-1.jpg"> <img src="blisshouse-2.jpg">';

preg_match_all('%<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/>%i', $content, $matches);
if(count($matches) > 0) {
    foreach ($matches as $matche) {
        $content = preg_replace('%<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/>%i', $matche[1], $content);
    }
}
echo $content;
```

Result is:

```
This fairy tale-like place is based on a story of two lovers who ran away to escape their enemies.
blisshouse-1.jpg blisshouse-1.jpg
```

Error can't replace `<img src="blisshouse-2.jpg">` to `blisshouse-2.jpg`. How to fix it

Comment: Don't preg_match and then replace in a loop. Just use preg_replace by itself, and with its substitution syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mario suggested - just use **preg_replace**

Also, I added a */?* because the **img** tags didn't have slashes.

```
$content = 'This fairy tale-like place is based on a story of two lovers who ran away to escape their enemies.
<img src="blisshouse-1.jpg"> <img src="blisshouse-2.jpg">';

$content = preg_replace('%<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/?>%i', '$1', $content);
echo $content;
```